# Displaying links to Weather sites and other widgets

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xhtml

What is the best tag to use to display widgets such as links to weather sites and Google maps? My old website used `<span>` with `src=` very satisfactorily, but `src=` isn't available for `<span>` in XHTML1.1. I've tried `<img>` and `<iframe>`. `<img>` only displays a red cross. `<iframe>` displays the widget OK but there is a difference between IE and Chrome, which both display it as I want, and Firefox, which puts a visible border round the widget, which I don't want. By the way, I would prefer a non Jquery/Ajax solution.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're setting src=?

Comment: This brings up the BBC Weather widget - `http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/2199/Next3DaysEmbed.xhtml?target=_parent`

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like an iframe is what you're looking for.  Style the iframe with border: none to remove the border from FF.

Comment: I have the following parms set for the `iframe` - `width=185px height=155px frameborder=0px` but it is still giving me a border when displayed in FF.

Comment: Try style="border: none;"  frameborder is either 0 or 1 (off or on)

Comment: style= doesn't work with iframe. If I replace `frameborder=0px` with `style="border: none;"`, I get a border with IE.

Comment: This worked for me in IE7,8; Chrome; FF 4.0 - width="185px" height="155px" frameborder="0" style="border: none;"

Comment: Changing it to `frameborder=0` rather than `frameborder=0px` removes the frame in FF. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: I think you will find that `style="border: none;"` has no effect if you remove it. It was the 0px rather than 0 that caused the problem.

Comment: heads up, frameborder has been deprecated in HTML5.  You'll need to use CSS to remove the border in order to have valid markup.

Comment: Wouldn't you just know it. That's the trouble with ASP.NET, MVC, C#, EF Code First, HTML, CSS etc. etc. etc. You get to know a way that works and then THEY go and change everything. Being at home on my own, I don't have enough time to keep reading the myriad of blogs just to make sure I'm using the lastest of everything. Ah well, press on regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `frameborder=0` fixes the problem.